# Save style of a text box MS Word 2007 or 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2007, styles

I've applied border, background and shadow styles etc. to a text box and would like to save this so I can use it for later use. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create your text box, while the text box is selected, select the "insert" menu.
click on the arrow below insert "text box" button.
select "save to text box gallery".
A box will come up, select your choices (i didn't change anything) and thats it.

When you want to insert your saved text box into a document,
select the "insert" menu
Click "Text box"
Scroll down, you will find it at the very bottom.

Regards
VJ

Answer (score 0):

I think, that the way to do it, is that you create a template, and copy that textbox there. Then when creating document based to that template, your textbox with all its styles is available for use.

Comment: That seems a very clunky way of having to deal with it. Surely they must have built in a way to do this? you can save text styles for example